# Creating an alias for NPM using cmder in Windows

Tags: windows, cmder

I'm using cmder on windows: http://bliker.github.io/cmder/

I've installed node.js from nodejs.org.

I can run npm in cmder by running this command:

`C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd`

Now how can I create an alias for this so I can just run, for example `npm install -g bower`?

I tried this:

`alias npm="C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd"`

But it reports back:

`alias npm="C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd"
Files\nodejs\npm.cmd""] was unexpected at this time.`

Answer (score 5):

If a file name includes spaces, it is necessary to use the 8.3 version of the name, like this:

`alias npm=C:\Progra~1\nodejs\npm.cmd $*`

You can get the short name by using command: `dir /x c:\`.

source: https://bountify.co/creating-an-alias-for-npm-using-cmder-in-windows

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add the folder containing npm to the "Path" system variable.

**To do that :**

- Go to "Computer" -> Right click on an empty space -> Properties -> Click "Advanced system parameters" which is located on the left panel
- A new window should have opened -> Select "Advanced system parameters" tab -> Click on "Environment variables"
- Then select the "Path" under "System variables" and click on modify.
- You should have something like :

> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\pub

- At the end, just add ";PATH_TO_NPM" (Don't forget the ";" at the beginning"
- Reboot your computer and it should be working.

Comment: You **don't** need to reboot your computer. To see the changes in your shell, simply open up a new instance - the new values will be visible there right away.

Comment: just need to reboot the terminal